# Cover an arbitrary element with another

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to cover an existing arbitrary element with another. All existing answers I have found require the element-to-be-covered to have a relative position. However, I am not in control of that.

For example, given a p element, I want to cover it entirely with a div element. The p element may not have a relative position.

Is this possible? If so, how can I achieve this (preferably without jQuery)?

Thanks!

Comment: SO you can not adjust the style to add the relative position to it?

Comment: Does it have to be an unique element? ergo, no `:before` or `:after` tricks

Comment: @epascarello I am worried this may change the page, this is not something I am allowed to do. I am trying to "highlight" an element, as done on Chrome developer tools, without changing the page in question.

Comment: So than you need to put the element outside of it and set the position absolutely and set the top,left,width,height, z-index

Comment: @Roberrrt I have access to the element in question and I must cover this element. I don't mind covering any child elements of the element-to-be-covered, but all others should remain uncovered.

Ideally without any `:before` or `:after` tricks

Comment: @epascarello this solved my question. Thank you!

Comment: @epascarello one downside of this solution is that you need to add listeners to determine when the page changes (i.e. when someone resizes the browser). Are there any potential css solutions without needing to add a JavaScript listener?

Comment: Yes, the one that you said you can not do. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit to @epascarello.

```
var elementToCover = ...;
var rect = elementToCover.getBoundingClientRect();

var overlayElement = document.createElement("div");

overlayElement.style.position = "absolute";
overlayElement.style.zIndex = "999";
overlayElement.style.top = rect.top + "px";
overlayElement.style.left = rect.top + "px";
overlayElement.style.width = (rect.right - rect.left) + "px";
overlayElement.style.height = (rect.bottom - rect.top) + "px";
```